# Layout = null; in view create System.NullReferenceException

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

When I try to Redirect to a specific view, my application throws a System.NullReferenceException at below specified statement.

This exception occurs in App_Web_*****.dll and is not handled in this detail.

I am not using any Masterpage or Layout in this application. I have tried to remove Layout = null and put ViewBag.Title = "SignUp", but it causes the same problem.

```
public class SignUpWizardController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /SignUpWizard/
    public ActionResult SignUpWizard()
    {
        return View();   //This Function Call Below View.
    }

}
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Login</title>
    <link href="~/Content/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/knockout-2.2.0.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/knockout-2.2.0.debug.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Content/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="~/ViewModel/LoginViewModel.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-custom" role="navigation">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <h2 class="text-center t-size-change">Login</h2>
        </div>
        <!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
    <div class="container m-t-150">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="login-tabs">
                    <!-- Nav tabs -->
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified nav-tabs-custom" role="tablist">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Login</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Sign up for free</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- Tab panes -->
                    <div class="tab-content">
                        <div class="tab-pane active custom-tab" id="home">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-12">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="email" placeholder="Email Address" class="form-control" name="Email" id="txtLogInEmail" required>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control" name="Password" id="txtLogInPassword" required>
                                    </div>
                                    <input type="button" value="Login to Tucan Rotas" class="btn btn-success btn-custom" id="btnLogIn" />
                                    <p class="text-center p-10"><a href="#">Forgot your password?</a></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="tab-pane custom-tab" id="profile">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-12">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="email" placeholder="Email Address" class="form-control" name="Email" id="txtSignUpEmail" required>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control" name="Password" id="txtSignUpPassword" required>
                                    </div>
                                    <input type="button" id="btnSignUp" class="btn btn-success btn-custom" value="Sign up for free" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="~/Content/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Content/js/tab.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $('#btnSignUp').click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    url:'@Url.Action("SignUp", "LogIn")',
                    method:"POST",
                    data: { Email: $('#txtSignUpEmail').val(), password: $('#txtSignUpPassword').val() }
                });
            });
            $('#btnLogIn').click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("LogIn", "LogIn")',
                    method: "POST",
                    data: { Email: $('#txtLogInEmail').val(), password: $('#txtLogInPassword').val() }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

For More information about Exception Please refer below stack trace.

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   ASP._Page_Views_SignUpWizard_SignUpWizard_cshtml.Execute() in d:\Scheduler\Scheduler\Views\SignUpWizard\SignUpWizard.cshtml:2
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +197
   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +96
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +76
   System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance) +257
   System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer) +115
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +294
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1a.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__17() +23
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +242
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__19() +21
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +175
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2a.<BeginInvokeAction>b__20() +89
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +102
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +57
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +43
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__18(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +14
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +57
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +47
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__3(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +25
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +47
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9651688
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: show the controller function for view

Comment: Hello, Please Check Question.I edited my question and put Controller And its method.

Comment: `Layout = null;` should not throw that exception. Show the full view.

Comment: I show full view.I try to put screenshot of error but due to less reputation,I can't able to put same.

Comment: Please Find Error Message Image.

Comment: Hi @ArjunBhalodiya I was having the same error until i started removing html chunk one by one and finally find out one of the property in model was null and that was the cause of exception. The error that mvc was throwing was bit misleading.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)